# Generalizations of Algebraic Closures

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, power-series, extension-field

Let's say we were to define some generalizations of the notion of an algebraic closure for a field $F$ that is equipped with a metric $d$ (or something that behaves like a metric for the purposes of discussing radii of convergence). Some specific examples could be:

-a "power series closure", defined as a field extension in which every non-constant power series with coefficients in the closure has a root, and every element is a root of a power series with coefficients in $F$

-an "$r$-power series closure" as the closure for power series of convergence radius less than or equal to $r$

-series with some generalizations of polynomials and perhaps even uncountable indexing sets for the sums, whenever they can be defined

-generally any closure for a specific class of functions, such as continuous, differentiable, or analytic functions

Has this notion already been explored somewhere, and if so under what name(s)? If not, then I have several exploratory questions:

-When would such closures exist?

-When would they be unique up to isomorpism?

-If they are not unique up to isomorphism, would there be some interesting ways to classify them?

-What would their relationships be, beyond the obvious relationships for radii of convergence?

-What would they look like for $\mathbb{R}$?

I appreciate any input, thanks.